# DataMapper, Model 

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model, connection, datamapper

I have a question about a '**modeling, training**' classes, there are two simple rules which do not fit in my head, and that such training should provide,

in my model, be it '`CustomersModel`, `VehicleModel`' I 'have' to have access to the methods of the writer of queries `(SQLBuilder)`, but also have access to the database, which would not set the mapper as the mapper works on the bench, and not the bank over the mapper, so complicated a little by my situation.

Imagine the following:

```
<?php
   // database access, mapping
   abstract class Mapper { }
   abstract class Model { } 


   interface Connection { } // to recognize it's a database access 
   class MySQL implements Connection { }
   class PgSQL implements Connection { } 

    // SQL Helper, some methods to write a update, insert, delete, select query
   class SQLBuilder { }

   // my custom models
   class Customers extends Model { }
```

visualizing this structure, the 'Customers', already has access to the mapper, in which case I would have a property '`$_table`' (among others) in the Customers table to recognize that this model works, but .. I do not have access to the writer of queries, and not to the database, for this, I thought of a method '`main()`', where setaria connection to the database, using the '`setDatabaseConnection ( Connection $connection )`' but the code would be often repeated, just imagine for N models, all using -> setDatabaseConnectiom, and the entire application uses only one database? ..

My question is basically that, provide access to the database without using setter method in model `(Customers, Vehicle)`, and the writer of queries right away.

Way i wan't to use is ..

```
<?php

       // my models
       class Customers extends Model { 

              // method of mapper does'nt implement
              public function getByCity ( $city ) {
                     $query = $this->select()->from($this->_table)->where('city = ?', $city);
                     $resultSet = $this->getConnection()->query( $query );
                     if ( $resultSet->rowCount() > 1 ) {
                            return $resultSet->fetchAll();
                     } else return $resultSet->fetch();
              }

       }
```

so how can I use the `save ()`, `delete ()`, `update ()` the mapper.
in this case, the `getConnection ()` method would have to get the default connection, and return the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several way to handle this. You can have a factory class that will instantiate your Model class. Somthing in the line of:

```
class ModelLoader {

    public function load($name)
    {
        $class = new $name();
        $class->setConnection(/* set connection class */);
        return $name;
    }
}

$loader = new ModelLoader();
$customer = $loader->load('Customer');
```

Another way can be by setting a default connection to be used when the connection in the model class isn't set.

```
interface Connection {}
class MySQL implements Connection {}
class PgSQL implements Connection {}

abstract class Model {

    private $connection = null;

    private static $defaultConnection;

    public function setConnection(Connection $connection = null)
    {
        if ($connection === null) {
            if (!self::$defaultConnection instanceof Connection) {
                throw new Exception('Default connection missing.');
            }
            $connection = self::$defaultConnection;
        }
        $this->connection = $connection;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getConnection()
    {
        if ($this->connection === null) {
            $this->setConnection();
        }
        return $this->connection;
    }

    public static function setDefaultConnection(Connection $connection)
    {
        self::$defaultConnection = $connection;
    }
}

class Customers extends Model { }
class Vehicle extends Model { }


Model::setDefaultConnection(new MySQL);

$customer = new Customers();
$customer->getConnection();

$vehicle = new Vehicle();
$vehicle->setConnection(new PgSQL);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($customer);
var_dump($vehicle);

// output
object(Customers)#2 (1) {
  ["connection":"Model":private]=>
  object(MySQL)#1 (0) {
  }
}
object(Vehicle)#3 (1) {
  ["connection":"Model":private]=>
  object(PgSQL)#4 (0) {
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

If your models "have to have" access to the database directly (via `SQLBuilder`) you're using the wrong pattern: *Data Mapper*. A *Data Mapper* normally does the SQL, so that's what it is for:

```
[Models]----[Mapper]----[Storage]
```

In your example it looks like that the mappers are hanging around somewhere but it's not clear for what they are as your models need to access storage directly:

```
[Models]---------[Storage]
   `-----[Mapper]---´
```

I suggest you implement the [Data Mapper as outline in the P of EAA Book<sup>*­Teaser*</sup>](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) which comes with code examples and discussion how to solve more complex SQL interaction within the Mapper Types and Supertype.

Alternatively *Active Record* with some common extensions per Model or some *Row Data Gateway* or *Table Data Gateway* might be suitable as well for your needs.